# How to check if folder already exists in google drive?

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a php script that uploads files from server to client's google drive, I have managed to upload files, and even inside a folder that I created using curl, but the problem is that I need to check if the client already has a folder with the specific name, if yes I must get the id and upload the file to that folder's id, here is the the code I used to make the file :

```
$folder_fields = "{\"title\":\"innitel\",
    \"parents\":\"[{}]\",
    \"mimeType\":\"application/vnd.google-apps.folder\"}";


$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $folder_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ARRAY("Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
    "Content-Type: application/json"));
    $reponse = curl_exec($ch);
```

This method will create a folder with the same name each time the script runs.
Is there a way to do?

Note : I can't use google-api-php-client because the php version of the server is 5.3 which is not supported.

Comment: Upgrade your PHP version. Seriously. 5.3. is considered to be unsafe and opened to a lot of possible hacking attempts which are covered in newer PHP.

Comment: You are right, but the problem is that the company i work with cannot do that because it will cause problems.

Comment: Sub-optimal code should not be used as an excuse to have security leaks. You need to fix all the problems in your local server, upload the code (pray) and fix any eventual problem you might find. If there is no time allocated for this, you need to tell the client that it is better safe than sorry.

Comment: @LajosArpad he was asking how to do it and not for some essay why not

Answer (score 2):

The approach depends on whether or not you have globally unique folder names. If the answer is yes, just do a files.list q title = 'foo'. If you get an item, there's the existing ID. If you get no items, you need to create it.

On the other hand, if you don't have globally unique folder names, you need to build fetch the folder hierarchy and check parents which is significantly more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do this approach as soon as i can and check if it works.